# Simple To-Do widget that syncs between phones

Tags: app-widgets, to-do-list

I have tried many widgets for a shopping/task list, but can't find one that fits my criteria. I would like it to:

1. Be SIMPLE - add and delete items right from the widget
2. Sync automatically between my wife's phone and mine
3. Not be date-based - I want to see ALL items until I complete them
4. Each item goes away when marked as complete

Any suggestions? Wunderlist is very close, but only shows "todays tasks".

Comment: I love Wunderlist but, like you said, the widget is seriously lacking. Do-It Tomorrow has a really nice looking widget but though the app is free, the widgets cost so I won't recommend that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Remember the milk.](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/) (RTM)

At least adding a todo from the widget is possible. You can use the widget to open the list of todos the widget is configured to display and then delete / mark as complete tasks.

You can share tasks with other RTM users (i.e. your wife). Tasks don't automatically go away from the widget (unless you configure it explicitly via a [smart list](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/answers/smartlists/createlist.rtm)).

Comment: That looks like a decent option. However, widgets are only available with PRO, which is $25/year (x2 for my wife!). I'd prefer free, but might settle on this one if nothing else comes along. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Todo.txt Touch](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.todotxt.todotxttouch)? (While it's $2 in the Market, if you don't care about getting automated updates, you can download it for free from the author's site.)

It expands on the simple philosophy of [Todo.txt](http://todotxt.com/) where your to-do list should just be a simple text file.

While you'll need to use Dropbox and share the file, once it's set up you don't really need to touch it except on your phones.

Here's how you'd set it up (assuming you and your wife share a computer):

1. Set up your todo.txt in a todo directory in Dropbox (basic Dropbox is free and is a great tool)
2. Install Todo.txt Touch on your phone and give it your Dropbox credentials
3. Repeat step 2 for your wife's phone
4. Now you have a shared, as-powerful-or-as-simple-as-you-need To-Do resource

Here's how you'd set it up (if you and your wife *don't* share a computer):

1. Set up your todo.txt in a todo directory in Dropbox
2. Share your todo directory with your wife's Dropbox account
3. Install Todo.txt Touch on your respective phones, using your own Dropbox credentials
4. Now you have a shared, as-powerful-or-as-simple-as-you-need To-Do resource

It seems like it might be a lot of work, but it's not. Further, you only need a simple text editor to work with your todo.txt file while at home.

Comment: Nice suggestion! I found your post here and this great article on Lifehacker. http://lifehacker.com/5859642/why-you-should-set-up-your-to+do-list-in-a-plain-text-file-and-how-to-do-it